when i click on submit button the login in form not response so what is the problem in my code
I  trying to login this is my php code  but dose not return any thing when I click submit even I enter correct password so password _verify not work in my browser or I enter the un correct coding I spent 3 days to solve the problem, but I could not solve it what is my problem ,I need help
I try when I enter submit with a correct password show hello but the website dose not appear any thing

Please don't post pictures of code. Instead, edit your question and put the code in here with proper formatting.

Unrelated to any problem (probably), running "escaping" or "cleaning" functions in order to make data "safe" for entry into a database is just asking for trouble and a false sense of security. Instead, use prepared statements for all user-supplied data that needs to go to the DB, and escape on render.

Please read [ask]. Pictures of code are unhelpful to other readers and those attempting to answer your question. You can [edit] your post. Thanks

Don't escape the password value when you're not putting it into the sql query!

With all due respect, just out of curiosity, are you following a tutorial? If so, I'd strongly recommend looking for another one. The <font> tag has been deprecated for at least a quarter of a century and it never (as far as I remember at least) accepted pixel values, only relative size units. So that along screams "run" to me, and that's not even touching the PHP problems.

Did you use password_hash() to store the password? Did you make the database Password column large enough to store a hashed password?

Yes I did and made password column varchar255

$clean_password=$db->real_escape_string(...) - how can you call this a "clean" password, when you apply a method that will potentially change the value? You need to compare the hash with the value as entered by the user, not with a value that might contain something else now due to database escaping being applied.
